# Setting numlock as a hotkey in Windows (by changing registry values)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

Recently I found [Microsoft Keyboad Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which can tweak the registry to add a new keyboard layout for a language. But it does not let the user change the capslock or numlock functionality.

Is there software for Windows 10 with which one can let the numeric keypad work as if:

- numlock is always on
- change numlock into a hotkey for switching between windows

This must be done by tweaking the registry; I'm not interested in keyboard hook software that needs to be running all the time.

Comment: I found an open-source tool called SharpKeys. I have never used it. Will it work for you? Available here: https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys

Comment: yes that has a numlock key.